# Javascript regex: discard end of string match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string preserving the newlines. The string can be everything, so the code must work in any case (new lines at begin of string, at end of string, consecutive new lines...).

I'm using this code:

```
var text = "abcd\nefg\n\nhijk\n"
var matches = text.match(/.*\n?/g)
```

which produces the following result:

```
[ 'abcd\n', 'efg\n', '\n', 'hijk', '' ]
```

That is what I need, except for the last match (`''`).

Actually I use `matches.pop()` in order to remove it, but I wonder if the regex could be improved in order to avoid that match.

Bonus points if you can explain why that match is present (I can't find any reason, but I suck at regexs :-) ).

Comment: Try removing the questionmark in the regex

Comment: What exactly is this regex supposed to do? I don't follow the results?

Comment: Use `.+` instead of `.*`. Also, I think you might first trim the string and then split by newline(s) instead of matching :) The explanation is simple: you made everything optional by using `*` and `?`. So at the end of the string there is no characters left, but hey `.*\n?` also matches empty string, so the regex engine will add it to the results as empty string.

Comment: This depends so much on what you want the regex to do. I suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info/ its a great resource on regular expressions

Comment: Sorry for didn't write what was my purpose; I wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternative:

```
var text = "abcd\nefg\n\nhijk\n";
var matches = text.match(/.+\n?|\n/g);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you tell which is the first argument of `|`? Is it `.+\n?` or just `\n?`?

Comment: @mdesantis: It is `.+\n?`

Comment: This is one of your favorite songs, right? "When you a match, I'll split you... When you want to split, I'll match you... Oh, honey..." :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#filter`:

```
var matches = text.match(/.*\n?/g).filter(Boolean);
//=> [ 'abcd\n', 'efg\n', '\n', 'hijk' ]
```

Or using a slightly different regex with non-optional `\n` (but it assumes new line is always there after last line):

```
var matches = text.match(/.*\n/g);
//=> [ 'abcd\n', 'efg\n', '\n', 'hijk' ]
```